# Charge protection thermistor proximity to battery

Tags: battery-charging, lipo, outdoors

I am working on designing a low power wireless sensor intended for permanent installation outdoors. Since this device will be used outdoors during the winter months I need to leverage the temperature protection features of my charge controller(TI bq24074). I understand that what really matters is the temperature of the battery, but am having a hard time finding sources for LiPo batteries with built-in NTC thermistors. I assume the next best thing would be an external NTC taped or glued to the side of the battery, but this adds complexity to assembly. Would an SMD thermistor on my charging board be adequate? The board and battery will be in close proximity in a small weather resistant container, so there shouldn't be much variance in temperature, but have yet to see mention of how accurate this temperature measurement has to be.

**TL;DR**, With the bq24074 and similar battery chargers, is it good enough to measure the temperature with an SMD thermistor if the board and battery are in close proximity?